# how to extract text between 2 regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
7.1 CAPITAL TITLE

text here
text here

7.2.2 CAPITAL TITLE
```

i want to get the following results:

```
7.1 CAPITAL TITLE text here text here
```

i tried to use regx as follows:

```
text = re.findall(r'[7]\.\d\s[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b(.*?)([7]\.\d\s[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b|[7]\.\d\.\d\s[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b|[7]\.\d\.\d\.\d\s[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b)', txt_extraction)
print(text)
```

the idea is to find the 7.X and the next title which could be 7.X or 7.X.X or 7.X.X.X and only then extract the title and the description of that title.
`[7]\.\d\s[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b` would find the `7.X CAPITAL LETTERS TITLES`
I thought `(.*?)` would find at least the text in between the titles, then i can build up from there but I got stuck :/
any help please?

Comment: Maybe `(?ms)^7\.\d[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*(?=.*?^7\.\d)`? See https://regex101.com/r/mKHwhX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern to match the title with only capital chars, and then match all lines that do not start with a digit followed by a dot

```
^7\.\d[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*(?:\n(?!\d\.).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `7\.\d` Match 7 `.` and a digit (use `\d+` for 1 or more digits)
- `[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+` Match 1+ spaces without newlines and then 1+ uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*` Optionally repeat the previous pattern
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\d\.).*` Match the rest of the line if it does not start with a digit followed by a dot
- `)` Close the non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U123UT/1)

Comment: Thank you for your time, it worked and really helped, but i have a new problem haha, how do i make it stop matching when if encounter a similar title type? ( exp: 7.1.1.1 TITLE text text 7.1.1.2 TITLE, i want to tell it to stop matching just before the 7.1.1.2)

Comment: i Tried this `^7\.\d\.\d\.\d[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*(\n)+(?:(?!7\.\d\.\d\.\d))* ` but not working

Comment: @AdemYoussef you can make the pattern more specific like this https://regex101.com/r/8fdpfb/1

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '''
 7.1 CAPITAL TITLE

text here
text here

7.2.2 CAPITAL TITLE

text here
text here


'''
new_string = ''
for line in string.split('\n'):
      if line.isupper():
          new_string+='\n'+line
     else:
          new_string+=' '+line
      

print(new_string)
```